# Can anyone suggest a faster method for creaing this array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am creating this array for my shader and this step is very slow as it constitutes a nested for loop. Currently this methos takes approx 1 sec to create this. Can anyone suggest any faster method for creating this array.

```
import numpy as np

elems = []
b = 23503  
a = 24 



for i in range(0, a - 1):
    for j in range(0, b - 1):
        elems += [j + b * i, j + b * i + 1, j + b * (i + 1)]
        elems += [j + b * (i + 1), j + b * (i + 1) + 1, j + b * i + 1]

elems = np.array(elems, dtype=np.int32)
```

Comment: if you're using `numpy` you should use `numpy` for the whole operation as it is significantly faster array operations that pure python

Comment: With ~500k iterations, is 1 second really that slow?

Comment: Are those loops really supposed to be `range(0, a-1)` and `range(0, b-1)`, i.e. up to and including only `a-2` and `b-2`? Each loop then has `a-1` and `b-1` iterations, which seems like an off-by-one error to me though I can't be sure without more context.

Comment: I feel these method is faster with the `dtype` argument chose to take up as little memory as possible.

elems = np.array(elems, dtype=np.int8)

Comment: @Raghavendra `elems.max() == 564071` here so he'll need at least those 32 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would recognise that there is a lot of repeated computation. The base term involving the iterator variables here is `i*b+j`, so let's have NumPy create an array that contains those values in the order they should appear:

```py
ib_j = (np.arange(a-1)[:, None]*b + np.arange(b-1)).flatten()
```

Next we compute the six different columns from this base, stack them horizontally, and flatten:

```py
def create_shader_array(a, b):
    ib_j = (np.arange(a-1)[:, None]*b + np.arange(b-1)).flatten()
    return np.column_stack((ib_j, ib_j+1, ib_j+b, ib_j+b, ib_j+b+1, ib_j+1)).flatten()
```

Validation:

```py
>>> all(create_shader_array(a, b) == AKS(a, b)) # AKS is your original implementation
True
```

Timing:

```
>>> %timeit AKS(24, 23503)
1.02 s ± 8.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit create_shader_array(24, 23503)
28.8 ms ± 364 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `meshgrid` to cover the i and j iterations and then to an outer add to get the inner shading. Using `ravel` in the end to get a 1D array.

```
inner = np.array([0, 1, b, b, b+1, 1], dtype="int32")
j, i = np.meshgrid(np.arange(b-1), np.arange(a-1))
elems = np.add.outer((j+b*i), inner).ravel()
```

or with a one-liner:

```
elems = ([0, 1, b, b, b+1, 1]+np.arange(b-1)[:, None]+b*np.arange(a-1)[:,None, None]).ravel()
```

Finishes in <6ms on my computer

```
In [9]: %timeit ([0, 1, b, b, b+1, 1]+np.arange(b-1)[:,None]+b*np.arange(a-1)[:
   ...: ,None, None]).ravel()                                                   
5.23 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit create_shader_array(a, b)                                      
29.8 ms ± 176 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```